# Excel: How do I view the source data of a graph from excel in word?

Tags: excel

I wanted to paste the graph from excel in word such that it is possible for me to view the source data of the graph.

What I did is to copy the graph from excel and paste it as link in word. I have two or more graph in the excel file (located in the same sheet). When I double click the graph in word it would take me to sheet of where the graph is located but not actually the graph.

What shall I do in order to be able to achieve what I want? That is when I click on the graph it would take me to its source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you have got your Chart created in let's say a workbook saved at C:\temp\foo.xlsx, now you copy and paste the chart in Word.

---

**Using VBA in Word**

Example

```
Sub ShowChartData()
    With ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).Chart.ChartData
        .ActivateChartDataWindow
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Without VBA.**

To view the data, make sure the Workbook is not open, then  just Right Click the chart and click Edit data, Word will launch your workbook foo.xlss and select the exact range containing the chart data.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.